# How to Run an Electrical Wire from a Breaker inside the house to the Deck

Tags: electrical, pvc, wire, siding

I just got a deck made at the back of a house in Alberta, Canada. House is wooden with PVC siding on the outside. I do have access in the basement to drill a hole and run a cable outside, but, not sure about couple of things.

What is the best way to waterproof the whole that I make on the side of the house to pull a cable from a new breaker. Do I need to run the conduit from inside the house all the way to the outside or is there a better way. I am planning to get 3 receptacles on the deck. Should I use flexible conduit or hard conduit.

My main concern is how to waterproof the hole made at the back of the house where the cable will come out. What kind of weatherproof joint box should I use.

Comment: Typically, you'd have a pull box or a junction box on the exterior to transition to your outdoor wiring. You can seal around these with silicone caulking pretty easily. The other parts of your question might be easier to answer if you provide a plan view of the house and deck, with breaker panel, cable runs, and receptacles identified.

Comment: Thank you and I will try to post photographs and plan view. Can you advise where can I get a pull box. Is is a fairly easy thing to find ?

Comment: You box store or electrical supply should have these.  Here are a few examples: https://www.lowes.com/pd/CARLON-2-Type-LB-Nonmetallic-Conduit-Body/3127635 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Madison-Electric-Products-1-1-4-in-Smart-LB-PVC-with-Cover-and-Gasket-KBLB121/300045277

Answer (score 1):

The item described as a "*pull box*" in the comments, is called a "*Conduit Body*".  But it will do nothing to seal the hole you'll drill through the house.

To seal around the conduit/cable, you can use [Duct Seal](http://www.idealindustries.ca/products/wire_installation/accessories/duct_seal.php).

[image: Duct Seal]

As for all the other questions you've asked. You should post another question for those, and include a lot more details about the project.